# Printing the whole object in one time with ToString() code needed

Tags: string, overriding, tostring

I wanted to know how can I print those 5 objects in 1 sentence.
This is my main:

```
        GAMES game1 = new GAMES("fifa", 300, 8.5);
        GAMES game2 = new GAMES("wwe", 250, 9);
        GAMES game3 = new GAMES("cod", 230, 8);
        GAMES game4 = new GAMES("nba", 360, 9.5);
        GAMES game5 = new GAMES("gta", 700, 6);

        Console.WriteLine(game2);
```

This is the Override code I wrote:

```
        public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Game Name:" + this.GameName + " " + "Price:" + this.Price + " " + "raiting:" + this.raiting;
    }
```

Now what I want to know is how can I print the whole 5 objects in one go please.

Answer (score 1):

You can add all games to an array and use foreach invoke method toString.

```
Array.foreach(elem => elem.toString)
```

Instead of Array, you type a name of your array.